# What's different between these two CSS implementations?

Tags: css

I have two versions of the same CSS (extracted from the same website) ... Only difference is that the second CSS set has lesser redundant entries ..

Because of some difference when the two, there is no text showing in the `Testimonials` section in the second version ..

Can someone tell me what's causing text to not show in the second version ?

Even in the second version, text has `display: block` on, but still it doesn't show .. In fact, I think all the CSS matches for the text (compared using Chrome Inspector), but still no text shows in the second set's Testimonial section ..

**Version 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/3hkwz/

**Version 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/SjDr7/

Comment: [Spot the difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference)? I love this game! (Seriously though, the "redundant entries" probably had effect on the specificity and which style trumped others)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Your question can't depend on external links to be answerable.

Comment: The CSS code is too big to be posted here .. If I did that, it'll probably put everyone off as there's a lot of CSS ..

Comment: In the second fiddle, I checked in chrome developer tools and it looks like the div with class .items (nested directly under a div with class .scrollable4) doesn't have a height set.

Comment: @Brad Christie: If by "redundant entries" you mean redundant comma-separated selectors, then unless they are matching the element they should have no effect on specificity. Given `<div class="foo">`, the specificity of a selector `.foo, div, div.bar` is equal to `.foo`, because it's the most specific selector that matches the element.

Comment: @BoltClock: TBH, I didn't go through the hundreds of lines looking for differences and took creative liberty on how redundancy was defined. I am aware of how specificity works, but (admittedly) may have made too broad an assumption without further investigating. I also commented because thought it wasn't a definitive answer, I felt it may hold some relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second CSS is missing a height declaration.

First file has:

```
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 .items {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And your second one has:

```
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 .items {
    width: 20000em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And is missing the:

```
height: 100%;
```

Therefore its height is getting set to 0px, and is not being displayed.
I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the declaration of:

```
width: 20000em;
```

Set the styles exactly as the first, and problem solved.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/SjDr7/) example.

Comment: If I add that CSS Rule, then the text does show, but see what happens when the next/prev buttons are pressed (at the bottom in testimonials view) .. In Version 1, the animation is correct .. In Version 2, its screwed up ..

Comment: Remove the `width: 20000em;` and your animation will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your inline css. Change line 68 of your html:

```
<div id="divleftcontent2" style="display: none;">
```

to something like this:

```
<div id="divleftcontent2">
```

Brad Christie had the right idea, since inline styles have the highest specifity.